# Trouble capturing IP packets with libpcap

Tags: endianness, libpcap

First the structs:

```
/* Ethernet addresses are 6 bytes */
#define ETHER_ADDR_LEN  6

/* Ethernet header */
struct sniff_ethernet {
    u_char ether_dhost[ETHER_ADDR_LEN]; /* Destination host address */
    u_char ether_shost[ETHER_ADDR_LEN]; /* Source host address */
    u_short ether_type; /* IP? ARP? RARP? etc */
};
#define ETHERTYPE_IP        0x0800      /* IP */

/* IP header */
struct sniff_ip {
    u_char ip_vhl;      /* version << 4 | header length >> 2 */
    u_char ip_tos;      /* type of service */
    u_short ip_len;     /* total length */
    u_short ip_id;      /* identification */
    u_short ip_off;     /* fragment offset field */
    u_char ip_ttl;      /* time to live */
    u_char ip_p;        /* protocol */
    u_short ip_sum;     /* checksum */
    struct in_addr ip_src,ip_dst; /* source and dest address */
};
#define IP_HL(ip)       (((ip)->ip_vhl) & 0x0f)
#define IP_V(ip)        (((ip)->ip_vhl) >> 4)
```

I have opened the network device with `pcap_open_live`, the `pcap_datalink` is `DLT_EN10MB` for that device, but I am receiving lots of IP headers with 0 length, weird version number, etc.
Here's a snippet that outputs this:

```
    eth = (struct sniff_ethernet*)(packet);
    ip = (struct sniff_ip*)(eth + 14); /* ETHERNET = 14 */
    int version_ip = IP_V(ip);
    int size_ip = IP_HL(ip)*4;

     printf("caplen=%d len=%d eth->type=%d version_ip=%d size_ip=%d !\n", header.caplen, header.len, eth->ether_type, version_ip, size_ip);
```

And some sample output:

```
caplen=94 len=94 eth->type=8 version_ip=0 size_ip=0 !
caplen=159 len=159 eth->type=8 version_ip=9 size_ip=12 !
caplen=110 len=110 eth->type=8 version_ip=0 size_ip=12 !
caplen=200 len=336 eth->type=8 version_ip=4 size_ip=20 ! (this one is OK)
```

What is going on here?

- Why is eth type 0x0008 and not 0x0800? Endianness?
- What's up with the weird ip header versions?
- How can the IP header length be below 20 bytes?

Comment: `ntohs(eth->ether_type)` fixes the first problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem...

```
eth = (struct sniff_ethernet*)(packet);
ip = (struct sniff_ip*)(eth + 14); /* should be (packet + 14) */
```

The 'smart' C pointer arithmetics doesn't add 14 bytes, but `14*sizeof(struct sniff_ethernet)`.